Confusing approximation for electric field generated by space charge
I am reading Gas Discharge Physics by Raizer, and I came along the following passage:

Let us evaluate the effect [of space charge], taking for the zeroth approximation the charge density distributions obtained in the assumption $E(x) =$ const. The spatial field distribution is determined by the equation
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}x} = 4\pi e (n_+-n_e), \, E \equiv E_x.$$
Assuming approximate equalities $n_+ \gg n_e, \; |j_+| \gg |j_e|, \; n_+ \approx \frac{j}{e v_{+d}} \approx \frac{j}{e \mu_+ E}$, and denoting by $E_C$ the field of the cathode, we find
$$E = E_C \sqrt{1-\frac{x}{d}}, \; d = \frac{\mu_+ {E_C}^2}{8 \pi j}.$$

Here, the subscripts $+$ and $e$ refer to the ions and electrons respectively. $n_.$ denotes the number density, $j_.$ denotes the current density, with $j$ the total current density, and $v_{.d}$ denotes the drift velocity.
I took the assumptions to mean that $n_+ - n_e \approx n_+ \approx \frac{j}{e \mu_+ E}$. The two inequalities are used to derive the least approximate equalities.
This confuses me, as the differential equation then in essence becomes
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{C}{E}$$
which clearly does not integrate to the given formula.
Where am I mistaken? Is there some dependency on $E$ I am not taking into account? Am I taking the assumptions too far?

I asked a colleague and we found the answer. TL;DR: Since $E$ is the function differentiated and not the variable, my intuition was very wrong.
With the approximations as given, the equation becomes
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4 \pi j}{\mu_+ E}.$$
We rewrite the equation as follows:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4 \pi j}{\mu_+ E} \\ E\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4 \pi j}{\mu_+} \\ \frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}E^2}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{4 \pi j}{\mu_+} \\ \frac{\mathrm{d}E^2}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+}.$$
Integrating both sites over $t$ from $0$ to $x$ gives:
$$\int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}E^2}{\mathrm{d}x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^x \frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+} \mathrm{d}x \\ \int_{{E_C}^2}^{{E_x}^2} \mathrm{d}E^2 = \int_0^x \frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+} \mathrm{d}x \\ -\int_{{E_x}^2}^{{E_C}^2} \mathrm{d}E^2 = \int_0^x \frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+} \mathrm{d}x \\  {E_C}^2 - {E_x}^2 = \frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+} x.$$
We changed the order of the bounds in the third line since $E_x < E_C$. From here, it is a straightforward rewrite to
$$E_x = E_C\sqrt{1-\frac{8 \pi j}{\mu_+ {E_C}^2} x}$$
which is precisely the answer from the book.
